# Laravel - actualizar solo los campos con valor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7

Tengo un endpoint que recibe ciertos parámetros por request y me gustaría que solo actualizara los campos que tienen valor, un ejemplo seria este.

En este código si le envío por parámetro **imagen_esp** y **pdf_esp** y el resto en null, me gustaria que solo actualizara los dos primeros valores.

Os dejo el código que tengo actualmente.

```
 /**
 * Upload images
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param int $id
 * @return ResponseFactory|Response
 */
public function uploadImagesEdit(Request $request, $id)
{

    $promocion = Promocion::find($id);

    $imagen_esp = $request->get('imagen_esp');
    $imagen_pt = $request->get('imagen_pt');
    $pdf_esp = $request->get('pdf_esp');
    $pdf_pt = $request->get('pdf_pt');

    try {
        Promocion::where('id', '=', $id)
            ->update([
                'imagen_esp' => $imagen_esp,
                'imagen_pt' => $imagen_pt,
                'pdf_esp' => $pdf_esp,
                'pdf_pt' => $pdf_pt
            ]);
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
        var_dump($exception);
        $aux = $exception;
    }

    return response('Imágenes subidas correctamente',200);

}
```

Comment: haz un array_filter con el request all, en el update coloca update(array_filter($request->all())) la funcion filter remueve todos los indices null, pero si va shacer asignacion masiva define bien tu fillable

Comment: Ayudaría a que te podamos brindar apoyo agregues aquello que hayas intentado